Contiue with next keyword even if previous keyword failed- Robot Framework
I have 2 keywords as below in a test case
Wait Until Page Contains Element             'Error element'    timeout= 200
Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element     'Error element'    timeout=100

I want the test to continue even if the error doesn’t appear on 1st keyword.
I tried below 2 options but it did not work for me.
Option 1:
Run Keyword And Ignore Error                 Wait Until Page Contains Element
...                                          'Error element'    timeout= 200       
Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element     'Error element'    timeout=100

Option 2:
${Ignore_Error}     Wait Until Page Contains Element     'Error element'    timeout= 200
Run Keyword And Ignore Error                             ${Ignore_Error}
Wait Until Page Does Not Contain Element                 'Error element'   timeout=100

I have also tried Run Keyword And Continue On Failure which did not work for me either
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Why is your element locator 'Error element'? Assuming that you are using the Selenium Library, have you referred to the Locating elements section for details about the locator syntax? You can also check out the Robot Framework's TRY/EXCEPT syntax to handle failures and exceptions.

Have you tried Run Keyword And Expect Error builtin keyword? For example:
*** Test Cases ***
My test
    Open Browser                    url=https://www.google.com/    browser=firefox
    Run Keyword And Expect Error    *    Find my element
    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Find my element
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //input[@value="Bing Search"]

In the example, element //input[@value="Bing Search"] is not visible on the Google search page and Run Keyword And Expect Error    * matches any error/string. Hence this keyword expects any errors and test case is passed. Hope this helps.

Thanks for the response.
However, in my test case, I need the first keyword checked and regardless it passes or fails, I need the test case to continue with the next keyword.
I just added 'error element ' in my code block for privacy purposes.
